# Delete [] causing segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, delete-operator

Can anyone tell me why a call to my delete2DMatrix function is causing a segmentation fault when run on G++ in ubuntu?

I run it in CLion and it executes perfectly and doesn't throw a segmentation fault, so I'm super confused as to why it's throwing a segmentation fault with G++. I've confirmed it is the delete function causing the segmentation fault. If I remove the function, everything executes perfectly.

My function is:

```
void delete2DMatrix(int ***matrix, int rows){
    for(int i=0; i < rows; i++){
        delete [] matrix[i];
    }
    delete [] matrix;
}
```

This is my function to create the matrix, so you can see I did call `new`:

```
int **create2DMatrix(int rows, int columns){
     int **matrixPtr;
     matrixPtr = new int *[rows];

     for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
         matrixPtr[i] = new int [columns];
     }

     //Sets all values to the default 0
     for(int i =0; i< rows; i++){
         for (int a = 0; a < columns; a++){
             addMatrixValue(matrixPtr, i, a, 0);
         }
     }

     return matrixPtr;
 }
```

I've confirmed the pointer being passed is actually pointing to the matrix. I've also been able to add values to the matrix with no problem. It's only when I call this delete function and only in G++ that it is throwing a segmentation fault and detecting a memory leak.

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: @Ron - Unfortunately while I agree, I cannot change it. My professor created his own .h file that we are required to use. He grades using his .h file so I have to leave it as ***matrix.

Comment: *He grades using his .h file* -- Well let me grade the C++ professor -- a big fat `F` for not teaching C++.

Comment: Devlopers using three-stars are typically the opposite of three-star-developers.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the way memory has been allocated for the matrix,

```
void delete2DMatrix(int ***matrix, int rows){
   ...
}
```

is not right. Use:

```
//                      ||
//                      vv Don't need the additional pointer.
void delete2DMatrix(int **matrix, int rows){
   ...
}
```

---

In a comment, you said:

> I cannot change the ***matrix in the delete because my professor created the declarations and we are not allowed to change them. He uses his own .h file when grading, so I have to use ***matrix.

In that case, you will need to use:

```
void delete2DMatrix(int ***matrix, int rows){
    int** ptr = *matrix;
    for(int i=0; i < rows; i++){
        delete [] ptr[i];
    }
    delete [] ptr;

    // I am guessing that your professor wants to have *matrix
    // set to nullptr in this function.
    *matrix = nullptr
}
```

---

It seems your professor's coding habits are still C-like. If they wanted to set the value of `matrix` to `nullptr`, they could use a more C++ idiom and pass a reference to the variable.

```
void delete2DMatrix(int**& matrix, int rows){
    for(int i=0; i < rows; i++){
        delete [] matrix[i];
    }
    delete [] matrix;
    matrix = nullptr
}
```

Comment: It doesn't explain the segfault. The code should not compile at all.

Comment: It compiles because I set a pointer equal to the value the create returned.

Comment: I cannot change the ***matrix in the delete because my professor created the declarations and we are not allowed to change them. He uses his own .h file when grading, so I have to use ***matrix in the delete.

Comment: @RaelynnS Well, first of all your code is incomplete. Secondly, we don't care about what your proffessor asks you to do. Triple pointer is more then likely a mistake.

Comment: @freakish, syntactically speaking, `matrix[i]` is of type `int**`. It is perfectly legal to use `delete [] matrix[i];` at compile time. So is `delete [] matrix;`

Comment: @RSahu Nah, for some reason I though `delete2DMatrix` was called on `matrixPtr`. Nvm, its late. :)

Comment: @freakish ok, well then is there no way to fix it without changing the .h file? Because that isn't an option.

Comment: @RSahu -- *It seems your professor's coding habits are still C-like* -- I will make the bold claim that the professor knows `C` and knows very little "real" `C++`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean the following

```
void delete2DMatrix(int ***matrix, int rows){
    for(int i=0; i < rows; i++){
        delete [] ( *matrix )[i];
    }
    delete [] *matrix;

    *matrix = NULL; // or *matrix = nullptr;
}
```

That is the function accepts a pointer to a pointer of the type `**matrix`.

So within the function you have at first to dereference the pointer as it is  shown above.)